# Passing props dynamically to dynamic component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've a dynamic view:

```
<div id="myview">
  <div :is="currentComponent"></div>
</div>
```

with an associated Vue instance:

```
new Vue ({
  data: function () {
    return {
      currentComponent: 'myComponent',
    }
  },
}).$mount('#myview');
```

This allows me to change my component dynamically.

In my case, I have three different components: `myComponent`, `myComponent1`, and `myComponent2`. And I switch between them like this:

```
Vue.component('myComponent', {
  template: "<button @click=\"$parent.currentComponent = 'myComponent1'\"></button>"
}
```

Now, I'd like to pass props to `myComponent1`.

How can I pass these props when I change the component type to `myComponent1`?

Comment: You pass props via attributes on the element `propName="propValue"`. Is that your question?

Comment: I cannot because I never write `<myComponent1 propName="propValue">` I change the component programmatically with `$parent.currentComponent = componentName`

Comment: Yeah but you write `<div :is="currentComponent"></div>`. That's where you'd add the attribute.

Comment: Yes but props depends of the component. For instance, `myComponent1` take props and `myComponent2` doesn't take props

Comment: Spent one hour trying to make this happen. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 332, accepted):

To pass props dynamically, you can add the `v-bind` directive to your dynamic component and pass an object containing your prop names and values:

So your dynamic component would look like this:

```
<component :is="currentComponent" v-bind="currentProperties"></component>
```

And in your Vue instance, `currentProperties` can change based on the current component:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    currentComponent: 'myComponent',
  }
},
computed: {
  currentProperties: function() {
    if (this.currentComponent === 'myComponent') {
      return { foo: 'bar' }
    }
  }
}
```

So now, when the `currentComponent` is `myComponent`, it will have a `foo` property equal to `'bar'`. And when it isn't, no properties will be passed.

Comment: Why this is not working for me?

It works for the first component, but after i change the “currentComponent” i get a “e.currentProperties” is undefined on child component.

Comment: @RicardoVigatti, without seeing any of your code, it's pretty hard to know

Comment: Hey, If I want to add something in `<component>(here)</component>` . It that possible?

Comment: @FelipeMorales, yep, you'd just need to define a default `<slot>` for each component you are dynamically rendering. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: The style guide says that prop names should be as detailed as possible. This way breaks the rule. This is also what I use, but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: @KorayKüpe you are mis-quoting the style guide here.  It says "prop definitions should always be as detailed as possible".  The intent of a dynamic component inherently means that prop names and structure will almost certainly be different between components loaded into this structure.

Comment: Don't forget to register props in the component you are dynamically rendering

Comment: What does the "is" do here? It doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere...

Comment: @seth See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @MCFreddie777 How do you 'register the props in the component you are rendering"?

Comment: Using computed() is an important aspect here; this made a difference for me.

Answer (score 30):

You can also do without computed property and inline the object.

`<div v-bind="{ id: someProp, 'other-attr': otherProp }"></div>`

Shown in the docs on V-Bind - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 21):

You could build it like...

```js
comp: { component: 'ComponentName', props: { square: true, outlined: true, dense: true }, model: 'form.bar' }
```

```html
<component :is="comp.component" v-bind="{...comp.props}" v-model="comp.model"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same challenge, fixed by the following:

```
<component :is="currentComponent" v-bind="resetProps"> 
   {{ title }}
</component>
```

and the script is

```
export default { 
  …
  props:['title'],
  data() {
    return {
      currentComponent: 'component-name',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    resetProps() {
      return { ...this.$attrs };
    },
}
```

```
<div
    :color="'error'"
    :onClick="handleOnclick"
    :title="'Title'"
/>
```

I'm came from reactjs and I found this solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

If you have imported you code through require

```js
var patientDetailsEdit = require('../patient-profile/patient-profile-personal-details-edit')
```

and initalize the data instance as below

```js
data: function () {
            return {
                currentView: patientDetailsEdit,
            }
```

you can also reference the component through the name property if you r component has it assigned

```js
currentProperties: function() {
                if (this.currentView.name === 'Personal-Details-Edit') {
                    return { mode: 'create' }
                }
            }
```

Comment: why function was used?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `<component>` inside a `v-for` you can change the answer of  [thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658979/1402958) as follow:

```
methods: {
  getCurrentProperties(component) {
    if (component === 'myComponent') {
      return {foo: baz};
    }
  }
},
```

usage

```
<div v-for="object in object.items" :key="object._your_id">
  <component :is="object.component" v-bind="getCurrentProperties(object.component)" />
</div>
```

Let me know if there is an easier way.

Comment: FYI, in a `v-for` (any list really), it's more performant to define a `computed` or `data` property that returns all the properties as an array and have your components select them by index.  Like `v-bind="currentProperties[object.component]"`.  Methods are called much more frequently than computed properties. (in my testing...)