# vuejs dynamic directive bound to data/computed value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use vuetifyjs for my html & css. One of it's components changes it's styling/behavior based on a custom directive (error || success || warning || info)

e.g.

```
<v-snackbar error></v-snackbar>
<v-snackbar success></v-snackbar>
```

Is there a way to bind the directive to a data or computed value?

something like this:

```
<v-snackbar {{ type }}></v-snackbar>
```

Comment: Those are not directives, they are props of the `v-snackbar` component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing props dynamically to dynamic component in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data property called `type` (or whatever you want to call it) that has the properties that you want to pass (say, `success`).

```
data:{
  type: {success: true}
}
```

And bind it to the `snackbar` component.

```
<v-snackbar v-bind="type"></v-snackbar>
```

Here is a [modified example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YxJvxP?editors=1010) from their documentation. In the example, click the Set Error or Set Success buttons to change the type.