# How to pass props / data to dynamically added components?

Tags: vue.js

So I have created this test [codepen](https://codepen.io/DapperMuffin/pen/eQxKQy?editors=1010) that allows me to add components on the fly to an already existing page, but the problem here is that I don't know how to pass props to them. I've seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs), asking something similar, where they were using a dynamic view switching across multiple components. But all of that is already done before the page itself is rendered.

With the click of a button I want to be able to dynamically create a component by name, ex:

- `<button-counter :input="'TestText'"></button-counter>`
- `<vue-header :input="'TestText'"></vue-header>`

What currently works is just creating the component dynamically, but without props. So placing something like button-counter or vue-header will be able to create the component (This goes for any component for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few minor modifications to your Codepen [on my fork here](https://codepen.io/ericnograles/pen/bQzxKz?editors=1010). You were very close!

The big difference is the implementation of `children` and how we render a dynamic component.

**Original**

```
const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    componentName: "componentName",
    input: "input",
    children: [
      buttonCounter,
      vueHeader
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    add () {
      this.children.push(this.componentName)
    },
  }
});
```

**Modified**

```
const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    componentName: "componentName",
    input: "input",
    children: [
      { componentName: 'button-counter', input: 'I am a button' },
      { componentName: 'vue-header', input: 'I am a header' }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    add () {
      this.children.push({ 
        componentName: this.componentName, 
        input: this.input 
      })
    },
  }
});
```

Likewise, your `v-for` changes on your template as well to accommodate the new shape of the `children` array:

```
<template v-for="(child, index) in children">
  <component :is="child.componentName" :input="child.input" :key="child.name" />
  <br>
</template>
```

So, as you can see, by making your `children` an object array which can then accept any props, you can pass those same props into the dynamic component. In this case, we have a prop called `input` for both of your custom components which are defined as part of this object array.

One thing to note is that, for Dynamic Components in Vue.js, the `is` prop can either accept the component itself (e.g. your original approach) *or a string representation of an already registered component*. That part there is the main differentiator between your original and my fork.

hth!

Comment: Holy crap, I never thought I could pass full object directly into this thing. 

Thanks for the help! I've been trying to get this working for ages!

Comment: np, glad to be of service :)