# Loop Over Array Of Vue Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to generate an array of Vue Components based on a config file I have of the different UI sections to show;

```
const config = [
  'summarySection',
  'scoreSection',
  'educationSection'
]
```

So somehow I'm trying to map this into an array of vue components that I can use in my template. I was thinking about doing something like this;

```
const availableComponents = {
  'summarySection': <summary-section/ >,
  'scoreSection': <score-section/>,
  ...
}

const sections = config.map((section) => availableComponents[section])

<template v-for="section in sections">
  {{ section }}
</template>
```

But this clearly doesn't work :/. Any suggestions?

**SOLUTION**

Here's how I solved this;

```
// In my config file;
const sections = [
  'profile-summary-section',
  'matchbars-section',
  'job-experience-section',
  'education-section',
  'skills-section',
  'about-section',
  'availability-section',
  'recruiter-notes-section',
  'transport-section',
]

// In my template;
<template v-for="section in sections">
  <component :is="section" :key="section" v-bind="sectionProps[section]"></component>
</template>

// In my computed variables;
sectionProps() {
  return {
    'profile-summary-section': {
      vIf: this.showSummary,
      class: 'mb-2 has-light-border bg-white',
      profile: this.profile,
      number: 0,
      showMatchPercentage: false,
    },
    'matchbars-section': {
     ...
    },
  };
},
```

Comment: see [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

```
const sections = ['summary-section', 'score-section'];

<template v-for="section in sections">
  <component :is="section"></component>
</template>
```

However, `section` should just hold the name of the registered component.

Comment: How would you add custom props for each component? Using the v-bind directive? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

Array sections should be a part of Vue component data, so that you'd be ablate access it in v-for. Also note that manipulations on the array should also be done inside Vue instance's special methods.