# Tag <component> inside Vuejs template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I just started to learn Vuejs, and in on one of the singe file components I need to work with there is a a structure that I don't clearly understand:

```
<template>
   <component :is="user === undefined ? 'div' : 'card'"> 
  
   ...some code

   </component>
</template>
```

In what cases it is useful? Why can't we use `<div>` instead?

I'm asking that question here because every time I google `Vue component tag` I am getting info about components themselves and nothing tag related.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<component>` is a special vue element that is used in combination with the `is` attribute.
What it does is to conditionally (and dynamically) render other elements, depending on what is placed inside the `is` attribute.

```
<component :is="'card'"></component>
```

Will render the `card` component in the DOM. The example shown in your code:

```
<component :is="user === undefined ? 'div' : 'card'">
```

will render a `div` when user is undefined, and a `card` component otherwise.

This behavior is dynamic, so if `user` changes from undefined to someghing else, vue will remove the `div` from the DOM, and will insert the `card` component.

In the HTML, you will never see a node called `<component>`, just a `div` or a `card`

Comment: I got it. Thanks! Do you have the link to the documentation?

Comment: You can find some information [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

Comment: Is it possible instead of `<div>` or `<card>` put a custom component with props required? If so, how should one pass the props?

Comment: yes it is possible. This should answer your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 2):

`<component>` is used when you need to dynamically render a specific tag (specified by `:is`) based on a certain piece of information (usually a `prop`). In the example you posted, you have two scenarios:

1. `user` is `undefined`, thus rendering `<component>` as a `<div>`
2. `user` is not `undefined`, thus rendering `<component>` as a `<card>`

`<card>` is most likely a custom component with its own specific template and logic.

Comment: Ohhh so `<component>` essentially transform into whatever html element is passed in as a `:to` prop?

Comment: `:is` attribute, not `:to` prop, but yes.