# Invalid Prop Type in Vue Component - Not the Type I'd Set

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm passing in components and properties dynamically [along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658979/15016489) (the idea is to 'stack-up' various components that I'll advance through)

Anyway, I've declared some properties on one of my 'stacked' components with their types as:

```js
  props: {
    pk: String,
    successUrl: String,
    cancelUrl: String,
    shippingAddressCollection: Boolean,
  },
```

However, when it's created, the component complains that my `shippingAddressCollection` does not have the expected type, which is:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "shippingAddressCollection". Expected Object, got Boolean with value false.

It's expecting an *object* instead of a *boolean*. How can this be?

Comment: You should check first what kind of data you're passing to the prop. If in your component you are passing an object like `shippingAddressCollection = '{ someProperty: 'Some value'} ', Vue is expecting your declared prop to be an object, not a boolean.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all ~ https://jsfiddle.net/9kp5wa1c/. Are you absolutely sure of your prop definitions?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming it's something to do with how I'm passing in the properties dynamically.

Comment: It can't be. The error message is literally telling you that your prop definition has `shippingAddressCollection: Object` or the equivalent of that

Comment: Would you show us the component from where you're passing the prop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The prop validation error is being thrown by @vue-stripe, not the component, like I'd assumed.

`shippingAddressCollection` is expected to be an object (see the [Props section under Getting Started](https://vuestripe.com/stripe-checkout/getting-started)).

But like the error says, it's being given a `Boolean` value. `shippingAddressCollection` should be a configuration object. It's not a simple `Boolean` flag indicating whether or not to request the shipping address.