# Conditional v-bind in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to put a `v-bind:something` conditionally?

I have this:

```html
<div class="sample">
   <div class="some-stuff" :handle=".handle" />
</div>
```

I want the `:handle` bind to be conditionally activated.

Having it duplicated with a `v-if` like this:

```html
<div class="sample">
   <div v-if="condition" class="some-stuff" :handle=".handle"/>
   <div v-else class="some-stuff" />
</div>
```

costs too much *performance*, as it has to **rerender** *a bunch of stuff* inside the `.some-stuff` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<div class="sample">
   <div class="some-stuff"  v-bind="{ [condition && 'handle']: '.handle' }" />
</div>
```

Got idea from:
[Passing props dynamically to dynamic component in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658481/passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs)

And from docs:

```
<!-- binding an object of attributes -->
<div v-bind="{ id: someProp, 'other-attr': otherProp }"></div>
```

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind